# Stored procedures both return results when executed in SSMS but only one does when executed from code

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, for-xml-path

I have two stored procedures, both written in SQL Server 2012 and both executed in SQL Server Management Studio which produce their results as xml.

However when these two procedures are imported into an Entity Data Model and then the functions to which they are mapped are called only one produces the same results as it does when executed from ssms.

I think that this must have something to do with one of the input parameters but given that they are not really that different I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

The two stored procedures are shown below. SPA works when executed from from both environments, SPB runs when executed in ssms with the date values entered in the parameters dialog box like so '2015-07-05', but fail when added as a date value (derived from a date drop down control) that produces a parameter like this #5/7/2015 12:00:00 AM#.

Can anyone spot some obvious faux pas on my part in spb that would prevent it from executing when called from code but still allow ssms to execute it properly.

**SPA**

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRange]
    @uname VARCHAR(10) ,
    @pword VARCHAR(10) ,
    @sntype VARCHAR(1) ,
    @action VARCHAR(10) ,
    @salesContractRef VARCHAR(10),
    @auctionId NCHAR(10) ,
    @startDate  DATE,
    @endDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT
    RTRIM(@uname) AS '@uname',
    RTRIM(@pword) AS '@pword',
    (SELECT
        @snType AS '@snType',
        RTRIM(@action) AS '@action',
        COALESCE(@salesContractRef, '') AS '@salesContractRef',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateOfPurchase, 112) AS '@saleDate',
        RTRIM(COALESCE(@auctionID, '')) AS '@auctionID',
        ISNULL(Logbook1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Logbook2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Logbook3 + ',', '') AS '@logBookNums',
        ISNULL(LandingDecNumber1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber3 + ',', '') AS '@landingDecNums',
        COALESCE(VesselName, '') AS '@vesselName',
        RTRIM(VesselPLN) AS '@vesselPln',
        RTRIM(VesselOwner) AS '@vesselMasterOwner',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate1, 112), '') AS '@landingDate1',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate2, 112), '') AS '@landingDate2',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate3, 112), '') AS '@landingDate3',
        RTRIM(CountryOfLanding) AS '@countryOfLanding',
        RTRIM(PortOfLanding) AS '@landingPortCode',
        RTRIM(lh1.LandingId) AS '@internalRef',
        (SELECT
            COALESCE(RTRIM(SpeciesCode),'') AS '@speciesCode',
            RTRIM(FishingArea) AS '@faoAreaCode',
            COALESCE(RTRIM(IcesZone),'') AS '@ZoneCode',
            COALESCE(RTRIM(ld.DisposalCode),'') AS '@disposalCode',
            COALESCE(ld.FreshnessGrade,'') AS '@freshnessCode',
            COALESCE(ld.ProductSize,'') AS '@sizeCode',
            COALESCE(ld.PresentationCode,'') AS '@presentationCode',
            COALESCE(ld.PresentationState,'') AS '@stateCode',
            RTRIM(ld.NumberOfFish) AS '@numberOfFish',
            FORMAT(ld.Quantity, 'N2') AS '@weightKgs',
            FORMAT(Quantity * ld.UnitPrice, 'N2') AS '@value',
            COALESCE(ld.Currency,'') AS '@currencyCode',
            RTRIM(ld.WithdrawnDestinationCode) AS '@withdrawnDestinationCode',
            RTRIM(ld.BuyersRegistrationCode) AS '@buyerReg',
            RTRIM(ld.SalesContractRef) AS '@salesContractRef'

        FROM LandingDetails ld
        JOIN LandingHeaders lh
            ON ld.LandingId = lh.LandingId
        WHERE ld.LandingId = lh1.LandingId
        FOR XML PATH ('salesline'), TYPE)

    FROM 
        LandingHeaders lh1
    WHERE 
        lh1.AllocatedErsId IS NULL 
        AND lh1.LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    ORDER BY 
        VesselName, lh1.LandingId
    FOR XML PATH ('salesnote'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('ers')
END
GO
```

**SPB**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLandingsToBePurchasedByDateAndPln]
        @startDate DATE  ,
        @endDate DATE  ,
        @VesselPln nchar(10) 
AS
BEGIN
    --SET LANGUAGE 'British English';
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT 
        (SELECT
             ContactId AS '@ContactId',
             VesselOwner AS '@Owner',
             FORMAT(Owed, 'N2') AS '@Owed',
             FORMAT(WeeklyDeductionRate, 'C') AS '@WeeklyDeductionRate',
             FORMAT(FromMinimumReturn, 'C') AS '@FromMinimumReturn',
             FORMAT(DeductionRate, 'P') AS '@DeductionRate',
             FORMAT(TotalDeductions, 'N2') AS '@TotalDeductions',
             FORMAT(TempReturn, 'N2') AS '@TempReturn',
             FORMAT(InternalCommission, 'P') AS '@InternalCommissionRate',
             FORMAT(InternalDeduction, 'P') AS '@InternalDeductionRate',
             FORMAT(InternalCommissionAmount, 'N2') AS '@InternalCommissionAmount',
             FORMAT(InternalDeductionAmount, 'N2') AS '@InternalDeductionAmount',
             FORMAT(TotalToBeReturned, 'N2') AS '@TotalToBeReturned',
             (SELECT DISTINCT
                  ld1.ProductId AS '@ProductId',
                  FORMAT(AVG(ld1.UnitPrice), 'N2') AS '@Cost',
                  FORMAT(SUM(ld1.Quantity), 'N2') AS '@Quantity'
              FROM 
                  LandingDetails ld1
              INNER JOIN 
                  dbo.LandingHeaders lh1 ON ld1.LandingId = lh1.LandingId
              WHERE 
                  Posted = 0
                  AND lh1.VesselOwner = a.VesselOwner
              GROUP BY 
                  ld1.ProductId
              FOR XML PATH ('Products'), TYPE)
  FROM (SELECT
    Contacts.ContactId AS ContactId,
    LandingHeaders.VesselOwner AS VesselOwner,
    SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) AS Owed,
    SocietyMemberships.WeeklyDeductionRate AS WeeklyDeductionRate,
    SocietyMemberships.FromMinimumReturn AS FromMinimumReturn,
    Deductions.DeductionRate,
    Vessels.InternalCommission,
    Vessels.InternalDeduction,
    CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END AS TotalDeductions,


    --need to add some logic here I presume that utiles the sql below that is being used to calculate the total to be returned


    SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
    (CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END) AS TempReturn,



    (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
    (CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END)) * InternalCommission AS InternalCommissionAmount,

    (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
    (CASE
      WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
      ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
    END)) * InternalDeduction AS InternalDeductionAmount,


    CASE
      WHEN (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) * InternalCommission > 0 THEN (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) + ((SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) * InternalCommission)

      ELSE (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) + ((SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) -
        (CASE
          WHEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) - (SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate) > FromMinimumReturn THEN SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate + WeeklyDeductionRate
          ELSE SUM(LandingDetails.Quantity * LandingDetails.UnitPrice) * DeductionRate
        END)) * InternalDeduction)
    END AS TotalToBeReturned





  FROM dbo.LandingDetails
  INNER JOIN dbo.LandingHeaders
    ON LandingDetails.LandingId = LandingHeaders.LandingId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Vessels
    ON LandingHeaders.VesselId = Vessels.VesselId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts
    ON Vessels.OwnerId = Contacts.ContactId
  INNER JOIN dbo.SocietyMemberships
    ON Contacts.SocietyId = SocietyMemberships.SocietyId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Deductions
    ON Vessels.DeductionId = Deductions.DeductionId
  WHERE (LandingHeaders.Posted = 0)
  AND (LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
    AND LandingHeaders.VesselPLN = RTRIM(@VesselPln)
  GROUP BY ContactId,
           LandingHeaders.VesselOwner,
           SocietyMemberships.WeeklyDeductionRate,
           SocietyMemberships.FromMinimumReturn,
           Deductions.DeductionRate,
           Vessels.InternalCommission,
           Vessels.InternalDeduction) a
  ORDER BY ContactId

  FOR XML PATH ('Owner'), TYPE)

FOR XML PATH ('PurchaseOrders')
END

GO
```

When executed from SSMS, SPB produces the following:

```
<PurchaseOrders>
  <Owner ContactId="39" Owner="M Mouse" Owed="1,609.39" 
         WeeklyDeductionRate="$10.00" FromMinimumReturn="$110.00" 
         DeductionRate="1.50 %" TotalDeductions="34.14" 
         TempReturn="1,575.24" InternalCommissionRate="0.00 %" 
         InternalDeductionRate="0.00 %" InternalCommissionAmount="0.00" 
         InternalDeductionAmount="0.00" TotalToBeReturned="1,575.24">
    <Products ProductId="33" Cost="5.00" Quantity="0.40" />
    <Products ProductId="34" Cost="1.80" Quantity="0.90" />
    <Products ProductId="41" Cost="2.30" Quantity="1.30" />
    <Products ProductId="42" Cost="2.25" Quantity="1.30" />
    <Products ProductId="43" Cost="1.60" Quantity="10.50" />
    <Products ProductId="57" Cost="7.00" Quantity="13.30" />
    <Products ProductId="59" Cost="9.63" Quantity="47.00" />
    <Products ProductId="61" Cost="6.23" Quantity="32.60" />
    <Products ProductId="66" Cost="1.00" Quantity="5.60" />
    <Products ProductId="92" Cost="0.50" Quantity="4.80" />
    <Products ProductId="125" Cost="1.00" Quantity="3.80" />
    <Products ProductId="139" Cost="6.50" Quantity="3.90" />
    <Products ProductId="156" Cost="1.50" Quantity="1.70" />
    <Products ProductId="161" Cost="5.80" Quantity="44.20" />
    <Products ProductId="171" Cost="3.88" Quantity="12.00" />
    <Products ProductId="173" Cost="4.55" Quantity="32.50" />
    <Products ProductId="175" Cost="5.00" Quantity="52.90" />
    <Products ProductId="182" Cost="0.50" Quantity="18.50" />
    <Products ProductId="198" Cost="0.50" Quantity="27.40" />
    <Products ProductId="220" Cost="1.50" Quantity="38.60" />
    <Products ProductId="231" Cost="6.00" Quantity="0.90" />
    <Products ProductId="236" Cost="0.85" Quantity="2.10" />
  </Owner>
</PurchaseOrders>
```

When executed from my app via the function created in the model it produces the following;

```
<PurchaseOrders/>
```

I'd welcome any suggestions.

EDIT

Here is the code as created by Devart's Entity Developer for SPA

```
Public Overridable Function CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRange (ByVal uname As String, ByVal pword As String, ByVal sntype As String, ByVal action As String, ByVal salesContractRef As String, ByVal auctionId As String, ByVal startDate As Global.System.Nullable(Of System.DateTime), ByVal endDate As Global.System.Nullable(Of System.DateTime)) As ObjectResult(Of CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRangeResult)
            Dim unameParameter As ObjectParameter
            If (Not uname Is Nothing) Then
                unameParameter = New ObjectParameter("uname", uname)
            Else
                unameParameter = New ObjectParameter("uname", GetType(String))
            End If
            Dim pwordParameter As ObjectParameter
            If (Not pword Is Nothing) Then
                pwordParameter = New ObjectParameter("pword", pword)
            Else
                pwordParameter = New ObjectParameter("pword", GetType(String))
            End If
            Dim sntypeParameter As ObjectParameter
            If (Not sntype Is Nothing) Then
                sntypeParameter = New ObjectParameter("sntype", sntype)
            Else
                sntypeParameter = New ObjectParameter("sntype", GetType(String))
            End If
            Dim actionParameter As ObjectParameter
            If (Not action Is Nothing) Then
                actionParameter = New ObjectParameter("action", action)
            Else
                actionParameter = New ObjectParameter("action", GetType(String))
            End If
            Dim salesContractRefParameter As ObjectParameter
            If (Not salesContractRef Is Nothing) Then
                salesContractRefParameter = New ObjectParameter("salesContractRef", salesContractRef)
            Else
                salesContractRefParameter = New ObjectParameter("salesContractRef", GetType(String))
            End If
            Dim auctionIdParameter As ObjectParameter
            If (Not auctionId Is Nothing) Then
                auctionIdParameter = New ObjectParameter("auctionId", auctionId)
            Else
                auctionIdParameter = New ObjectParameter("auctionId", GetType(String))
            End If
            Dim startDateParameter As ObjectParameter
            If (startDate.HasValue) Then
                startDateParameter = New ObjectParameter("startDate", startDate)
            Else
                startDateParameter = New ObjectParameter("startDate", GetType(Global.System.Nullable(Of System.DateTime)))
            End If
            Dim endDateParameter As ObjectParameter
            If (endDate.HasValue) Then
                endDateParameter = New ObjectParameter("endDate", endDate)
            Else
                endDateParameter = New ObjectParameter("endDate", GetType(Global.System.Nullable(Of System.DateTime)))
            End If
            Return DirectCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(Of CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRangeResult)("FishTrackerProfessionalEntities.CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRange", unameParameter, pwordParameter, sntypeParameter, actionParameter, salesContractRefParameter, auctionIdParameter, startDateParameter, endDateParameter)
        End Function
```

and it is called in my code like so:

```
 Using ftpe = New FishTrackerProfessionalEntities
        Try
            Dim result = ftpe.CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRange("uname", "pword", "B", "INSERT", String.Empty, String.Empty, ErsStartDate, ErsEndDate)
            xmlValue = String.Join(String.Empty, result.Select(Function(r) r.XMLF52E2B6118A111d1B10500805F49916B))
        Catch Ex As Exception
```

ErsStart and end dates are properties of type Date bound to date edit controls.

For Spb we have:

```
Public Overridable Function GetLandingsToBePurchasedByDateAndPln (ByVal startDate As Global.System.Nullable(Of System.DateTime), ByVal endDate As Global.System.Nullable(Of System.DateTime), ByVal VesselPln As String) As ObjectResult(Of CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRangeResult)
        Dim startDateParameter As ObjectParameter
        If (startDate.HasValue) Then
            startDateParameter = New ObjectParameter("startDate", startDate)
        Else
            startDateParameter = New ObjectParameter("startDate", GetType(Global.System.Nullable(Of System.DateTime)))
        End If
        Dim endDateParameter As ObjectParameter
        If (endDate.HasValue) Then
            endDateParameter = New ObjectParameter("endDate", endDate)
        Else
            endDateParameter = New ObjectParameter("endDate", GetType(Global.System.Nullable(Of System.DateTime)))
        End If
        Dim VesselPlnParameter As ObjectParameter
        If (Not VesselPln Is Nothing) Then
            VesselPlnParameter = New ObjectParameter("VesselPln", VesselPln)
        Else
            VesselPlnParameter = New ObjectParameter("VesselPln", GetType(String))
        End If
        Return DirectCast(Me, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(Of CreateErsSalesAddSubmissionXmlByDateRangeResult)("FishTrackerProfessionalEntities.GetLandingsToBePurchasedByDateAndPln", startDateParameter, endDateParameter, VesselPlnParameter)
    End Function
```

And it's called like so;

```
 Using ftpe = New FishTrackerProfessionalEntities
        Try
            Dim result = ftpe.GetLandingsToBePurchasedByDateAndPln(StartDate, EndDate, VesselPln)
            xmlValue = String.Join(String.Empty, result.Select(Function(r) r.XMLF52E2B6118A111d1B10500805F49916B))
        Catch Ex As Exception
```

with Start and End date being properties of type date.

Comment: This is very likely some problem with the `@VesselPln` parameter value or how you are passing it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung In both cases (ssms and from code, it is being passed as a sting.  In the case of the results that I placed in the question that string was "RX89". The underlying data type of VesselPln is Nchar(10).

Comment: You should show us the calling code for both cases.  That is, show us explicitly how you are invoking SPB both in code and from SSMS.

Comment: Have added relevant code.

Comment: Can you run a profiler trace to make sure it's not casting the variable or replacing as an empty string instead of passing null?

Comment: @DomSinclair, I assume `GetLandingsToBePurchasedByDateAndPln` is in the `DBO` Schema in the model, correct?  Looks like your `ExecuteFunction` declaration is mal-formed.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely the problem is the parameters, and in my experience, dates are always a mess..

The most common problem is the month-day inversion, it happens on various scenarios, for example implicit conversion between date and datetime.
take a look at this:

```
declare @d1 date = '2016-02-03'
declare @d2 datetime = '2016-02-03'
select FORMAT(@d1, 'yyyy-MMMM-dd') ParDate, FORMAT(@d2, 'yyyy-MMMM-dd') ParDateTime
```

the result is funny:

```
ParDate             ParDateTime
2016-febbraio-03    2016-marzo-02
```

So you can try to debug your SPB, modify the `WHERE` clause of `PATH ('Owner')` in SPB.
Temporarly rem both the conditions on `@startDate/@endDate` and `@VesselPln`

```
-- AND (LandingDate1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
-- AND LandingHeaders.VesselPLN = RTRIM(@VesselPln)
```

Then try to call it from your app, it should return all results.
Then re-add the condition on `@VesselPln`, test it, I think it will still output something.

If not, you have already found your problem, maybe something related to multybyte strings `nchar(10)` or less likely something related to ansi paddings and trailing spaces.

If yes, add `@startDate` and `@endDate` to `SELECT` section of `PATH ('Owner')` to check how they are viewed by the SPB:

```
FORMAT(@startDate, 'yyyy-MMMM-dd') as '@StartDate', 
FORMAT(@endDate, 'yyyy-MMMM-dd') as '@EndDate',
```

This way you should see in your xml output what's the problem.

I hope this helps.